# Como implementar um algorítimo de permutação em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, criptografia

Estou tentando implementar um algorítimo de permutação em Python.

Ele recebe como entrada uma **frase** e uma **chave** (valor numérico) que corresponde a quantidade de letras que cada grupo deve ter, e por fim, uma **sequência numérica** que vá de 1 até o valor da chave.

Segue um exemplo de entrada de dados:

Frase de entrada:

> "Python é a melhor linguagem!!"

Chave de entrada:

> 5

Sequencia de entrada:

> 4 2 5 1 3

Saída esperada:

> Hyopt
>   méena
>   rhllo
>   unaig
>   !e!gm

---

Segue a minha tentativa, porém sem resultado, porque eu não estou conseguindo implementar e fazer a divisão por grupos para obter o resultado ilustrado no exemplo.

Código:

```
contador = 0            
frase = input('Digite uma frase: ').upper
chave = int(input('Digite a chave: '))
seq = []

while contador <= chave:    
  seq.append(int(input('Digite o número da sequência: ')))

frase = frase.split()
frase = ''.join(frase)
```

Comment: Qual é exatamente a lógica para gerar a saída esperada?

Comment: 1º Juntar a frase em uma palavra só 2º Dividir em grupos de letras 3º Trocar a ordem de cada letra dentro de cada grupo, conforme a sequencia informada

Comment: E qual o critério para definir os grupos de letras no passo 2? Ter o número de caracteres definido pela chave?

Comment: O critério é o valor da chave informada, que corresponde a quantidade de letras em cada grupo

Comment: E se o comprimento do texto não for múltiplo da chave, o último grupo irá possuir menos caracteres? Se a chave for 5 e o texto possuir 12 caracteres, irá criar grupos de 5, 5 e 2 caracteres?

Comment: O último grupo deverá ser preenchido com caracteres asterisco *

Comment: Certo, depois de definido os grupos, qual a lógica para permutar os caracteres baseado na sequência de entrada? Apenas deslocar os caracteres dentro do próprio grupo?

Comment: Os números da sequência correspondem  a posição de cada caractere. Por exemplo: No grupo de caracteres "cafe",  com sequencia "3 1 4 2" o grupo passará a ter a sequência de caracteres na seguinte ordem: "fcea". Significa que o caractere da posição 3 passará a ocupar a posição 1, o caractere da posição 1 passará a ocupar a posição 2, e assim por diante

Comment: Agora sim ficou claro. Respondo assim que possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separação do texto em grupos pode ser feito através de uma compreensão de lista, acessando as posições `i:i+key` do texto, onde `i` varia de 0 até o comprimento do texto, com passo igual a `key`. Quando o último grupo não possui a quantidade necessária de caracteres, é adicionado `*` utilizando o método `ljust`. Após, é percorrido os grupos e feita a permutação entre os caracteres.

```
# Frase de entrada:
text = input("Entre com uma frase: ")

# Chave de entrada:
key = int(input("Entre com uma chave: "))

# Sequência de entrada:
sequence = []
for i in range(key):
    sequence.append(int(input("Entre com um número da sequência: ")))

# Remove os espaços em branco do texto:
text = text.replace(" ", "")

# Divide o texto em grupos definidos pela chave:
groups = [text[i:i+key].ljust(key, "*") for i in range(0, len(text), key)]

# Percorre os grupos gerando os novos grupos:
result = []
for group in groups:
    output = ""
    for i in sequence:
        output += group[i-1]
    result.append(output)

print(result)
```

Com as entradas apresentadas na pergunta, a saída é:

```
['hyoPt', 'méena', 'rhllo', 'unaig', '!e!gm']
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ErK5PZ).