# Como funciona o comando "for" inline?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, for

Fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238651/91830) a respeito de um algoritmo em Python, porém, na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238744/91830) do [usuário Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) ele utilizou um tipo de `for` *inline* que eu nunca havia visto e que me deixou confuso.

Segue o trecho de código correspondente ao `for`:

```
groups = [text[i:i+key].ljust(key, "*") for i in range(0, len(text), key)]
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o que é esta expressão `for` *inline* e como ela funciona?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459254/d%c3%a1-para-fazer-o-for-em-1-linha/459263#459263).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Esta forma é a chamada compreensão de listas, ou no inglês [*list comprehensions*](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk). Ela nada mais é que uma forma simplificada de se escrever um laço `for`. Neste caso eu tenha até utilizado de maneira inadequada, pois o código final não ficou tão legível quanto deveria ficar em um código Python, mas o código equivalente a este seria:

```
groups = []

for i in range(0, len(text), key):
    value = text[i:i+key]          # Pega o trecho da string de i até i+key
    value = value.ljust(key, "*")  # Garante que a string possua "key" caracteres, adicionando *
    groups.append(value)           # Adiciona o valor final à lista
```

Este código acima, para fins práticos, faz exatamente a mesma coisa que a linha apresentada na pergunta:

```
groups = [text[i:i+key].ljust(key, "*") for i in range(0, len(text), key)]
```

É definida esta sintaxe para deixar o código mais conciso e muito mais legível - pelo menos essa é o objetivo (nem sempre utilizada corretamente hehe). Em fontes não oficiais, pode-se ler que a compreensão de listas é até mais rápida que um `for` normal devido principalmente à implementações internas da linguagem. Particularmente nunca tentei comprovar isso na prática e não lembro de ver alguma fonte oficial que comprove isso, mas, no mínimo, tem a mesma performance, então pode usar sem medo.

Inclusive, pode-se utilizar a compreensão de listas de forma aninhadas, por exemplo, para percorrer uma "matriz", que necessita de um `for` para as linhas e outro para as colunas.

```
matrix = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

double_matrix = [[2*matrix[i][j] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
```

O resultado seria a "matriz" multiplicada por 2:

```
[
  [ 2,  4,  6],
  [ 8, 10, 12],
  [14, 16, 18]
]
```

Pois o código equivalente seria:

```
matrix = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

double_matrix = []

for i in range(3):
    row = []
    for j in range(3):
        row.append(2*matrix[i][j])
    double_matrix.append(row)
```

**Referências**

[Documentação oficial: List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

---

Esta sintaxe também é válida para definir dicionários. Supondo que desejamos criar um dicionário com chaves inteiras de 0 a 4, cujo o valor no dicionário refere-se ao dobro da chave. Com um laço `for`, poderíamos fazer:

```
d = {}

for i in range(5):
    d[i] = 2*i

print(d)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/UNzATJ).

A sintaxe utilizando *dict comprehensions* seria:

```
d = {i: 2*i for i in range(5)}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/8IW2J1).

A principal diferença é que, enquanto a compreensão de listas é definida entre colchetes, `[]`, que é a sintaxe de listas, a compreensão de dicionários é definida entre chaves, `{}`, que é a sintaxe de dicionários, além de definir o par chave/valor e `i: 2*i`.

---

Dito isso, é possível pensar que também seria possível definir uma tupla com esta sintaxe apenas utilizando entre parenteses, `()`, que é a sintaxe de tupla. Errado. A tupla é um tipo imutável do Python e, portanto, não poderia ser alterada junto ao laço `for`, mas isso não significa que a sintaxe utilizando os parenteses esteja errada.

Na verdade, quando utilizado os parenteses, o que é definido é um gerador. Isto é, fazer algo como:

```
g = (2*i for i in range(5))
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/LbybKW).

Seria o mesmo que:

```
def temp():
    for i in range(5):
        yield 2*i

g = temp()
```

Nestes casos, você poderia iterar sobre o gerador ou simplesmente convertê-lo para uma lista:

```
l = list(g)

print(l)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/oGmzxM).

Em alguns casos seria possível omitir os parenteses, então quando ver a sintaxe sem os parenteses, saiba que também é uma definição de um gerador. Para citar um exemplo, o cálculo da soma dos valores entre 0 e 5:

```
s = sum(i for i in range(5))
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Qyv7cW).

Comment: Também é possível fazer compreensão de dicionários, né? Funciona mais ou menos assim eu acho

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim, é possível, assim como também é possível definir um gerador com esta sintaxe removendo os colchetes.

Answer (score 11):

Isto é basicamente o mesmo que escrever

```
for i in range(0, len(text), key)]
    groups = groups + [text[i:i + key].ljust(key, "*")
```

Conhece outras linguagens? O [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-range) gera um sequência numérica como se fosse

```
for (int i = 0; i < len(text); i+= key)
```

A função [`ljust()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=ljust#str.ljust) faz um *padding* então ela repete um determinado caracteres quantas vezes forem necessárias até preencher como tamanho desejado. Ela faz isso com, um objeto obtido anteriormente com a expressão

```
text[i:i + key]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/ForExplain.py).

Isto é um [*slice*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html), ou seja ele pega uma coleção de dados, no caso uma coleção de caracteres, também conhecida como *string* estabelece em qual caractere vai começar pegar, no caso o valor de `i` e até que posição deve pegar, no caso `i + key`, ou seja, ele pega a quantidade de caracteres do incremento do `for`.

[Documentação do `for`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop). E [sobre estruturas de controle de fluxo em geral](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html).