# Qual o nome da função antes do loop for em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá venho da linguagem c++ e java, e estou aprendendo python. Me deparei com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
data = {'Player'    :   ['Wade', 'James', 'Kobe', 'Curry'],
    'First'     :   [10, 10, 8, 12],
    'Second'    :   [12, 8, 13, 8],
    'Third'     :   [15, 12, 8, 8],
    'Fourth'    :   [18, 20, 15, 8] }

bar_width = 0.5

bars = [i + 1 for i in range(len(data['First']))]
ticks = [i + (bar_width/2) for i in bars]
```

O loop for consigo entender perfeitamente, porém não entendi a expressão **i + 1** e **i + (bar_width/2)** que vem antes do **for**. Gostaria de saber o nome disso, pra pelo menos começar a procurar, ou se alguém tiver algum artigo, poderia compartilhar?
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Está na mão: [Como funciona o comando “for” inline?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240948/5878)

Comment: `[i + 1 for i in range(len(data['First']))]` pode ser lido como `[1+1, 2+1, 3+1, 4+1]`. Sendo que i vai de 1 a 4 por causa dessa instrução: `for i in range(len(data['First']))` que por sua vez cria uma faixa (range) do comprimento (len) da lista de índice 'First' (que tem 4 ítens)

Comment: Esse [artigo](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) explica bem isso

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal!

Comment: Para quem quiser procurar por isso, o nome é `list comprehension` -  e há os correlatos `generator expression`, `set comprehension` e  `dict comprehension`.