# Declaração for com 2 argumentos, como funciona?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, for, return

Vi essa declaração em um código no `codewars` e não consegui entender como funciona:

```
def multiple_of_index(arr):
    return [val for index, val in enumerate(arr) if index and val % index == 0]
```

`enumarate(arr)` cria uma lista de tuplas que contem o `index` e `value` de forma similar a uma variável do tipo `dictionary` certo?

Neste caso, a declaração `for` irá iterar pela lista de tuplas geradas pelo `enumarate` duas vezes? Uma para o argumento `index` e outra para o argumento `val`?

E como a declaração `if` irá funcionar? A declaração `for` irá iterar apenas se a declaração `if` retornar `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def multiple_of_index(arr):
    return [val for index, val in enumerate(arr) if index and val % index == 0]
```

O parâmetro `arr` será de um tipo iterável. A função `enumerate` irá percorrer os valores de `arr` e **gerar** uma tupla de dois valores: o primeiro valor será a posição do valor iterado dentro do objeto original e o segundo valor será o valor presente no objeto iterado.

Imaginando uma lista `['a', 'b', 'c']`, o `enumerate` geraria os pares de valores: `(0, 'a')`, `(1, 'b')` e `(2, 'c')`. Note que eu sempre digo "gerar", pois o retorno da função é um gerador - um dos tipos iteráveis do Python característico por efetuar o *lazy-evaluation*.

Através da desconstrução de tuplas, o par de valores gerados pelo `enumerate` será atribuído às variáveis `index` e `val` no trecho `index, val in enumerate(arr)`.

A partir disso é construído uma compreensão de lista (*list comprehension*) contendo o valor de `val` quando a condição é satisfeita. Neste caso a condição é `if index and val % index == 0`, isto é, se `index` for avaliado como verdadeiro e `val` for múltiplo de `index`. O valor de `index` somente será avaliado como falso quando valor 0, portanto a condição será se `index` for diferente de 0 e `val` for múltiplo de `index`. Quando a condição for satisfeita o valor de `val` entrará na lista final, sendo retornada da função.

O código equivalente é:

```
def multiple_of_index(arr):
    result = []
    index = 0
    for val in arr:
        if index != 0 and val % index == 0:
            result.append(val)
        index += 1
    return result
```

Relacionada:

- [Como funciona o comando "for" inline?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240948/5878)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo detalhamento, consegui compreender a lógica da expressão