# Como faço para multiplicar duas matrizes no python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

```
def multM(a, b): '''essa foi a função que eu tentei fazer'''
    if len(a) == len(b[0]):
        r = []
        for i in range(len(a)):
            r.append([])
            for j in range(len(b[0])):
                for k in range(len(a)):
                    val = a[i][j] * b[k][i]
                r[-1].append(val)
    return r
```

Comment: Já considerou usar o `np.matmul(a,b)` ?

Comment: Já, mas isso é para uma atividade e eu tenho que criar uma função para isso mesmo assim, obrigado!

Comment: Bom. Espero que vc queira fazer isso somente pra treinar. Porque não tem muito sentido. O mais adequado é usar uma biblioteca como o numpy.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer duas funções:

- `getLinha(matriz, n)` retorna uma lista com os valores da linha `n`.
- `getColuna(matriz, n)` retorna uma lista com os valores da coluna `n`.

Implementando, temos:

```
def getLinha(matriz, n):
    return [i for i in matriz[n]]  # ou simplesmente return matriz[n]

def getColuna(matriz, n):
    return [i[n] for i in matriz]

mat1 = [[2, 3], [4, 6]]            # uma matriz 2x2
mat1lin = len(mat1)                # retorna 2
mat1col = len(mat1[0])             # retorna 2

mat2 = [[1, 3, 0], [2, 1, 1]]      # uma matriz 2x3
mat2lin = len(mat2)                # retorna 2
mat2col = len(mat1[0])             # retorna 3

matRes = []                        # deverá ser uma matriz 2x3
for i in range(mat1lin):           
    matRes.append([])

    for j in range(mat2col):
        # multiplica cada linha de mat1 por cada coluna de mat2;
        listMult = [x*y for x, y in zip(getLinha(mat1, i), getColuna(mat2, j))]

        # e em seguida adiciona a matRes a soma das multiplicações
        matRes[i].append(sum(listMult))

print(matRes)
```

Rodar o código gera como saída `[[8, 9, 3], [16, 18, 6]]`.

Usando classes ficaria mais prático:

```
class Matriz:
    def __init__(self, mat):
        self.mat = mat
        self.lin = len(mat)
        self.col = len(mat[0])

    def getLinha(self, n):
        return [i for i in self.mat[n]]

    def getColuna(self, n):
        return [i[n] for i in self.mat]

    # opcional: dar overload no operador de multiplicação
    def __mul__(self, mat2):
        matRes = []

        for i in range(self.lin):           
            matRes.append([])

            for j in range(mat2.col):
                listMult = [x*y for x, y in zip(self.getLinha(i), mat2.getColuna(j))]
                matRes[i].append(sum(listMult))

        return matRes
```

Rodar esse código usando

```
mat1 = Matriz([[2, 3], [4, 6]])
mat2 = Matriz([[1, 3, 0], [2, 1, 1]])
print(mat1*mat2)
```

dá como saída `[[8, 9, 3], [16, 18, 6]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) e a [compreensão de lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240948/como-funciona-o-comando-for-inline/240951#240951).
A função zip toma listas e constrói uma lista de tuplas com os membros das listas. E a compreensão de lista é uma maneira mais rápida de se escrever laços for simples.

Este é basicamente o código:

```py
numerosX = [3, 5, 7, 11]
numerosY = [4, 6, 8, 12]

numerosZ = [x*y for x, y in zip(numerosX, numerosY)]
print(numerosZ) # Imprime [12, 30, 56, 132]
```

Comment: Só lembrando que multiplicação de matrizes não basta multiplicar elemento por elemento. A multiplicação de matrizes sempre considerará a multiplicação entre uma linha e uma coluna, fazendo com que uma matriz 1:4 multiplicada por uma 4:1 resultaria em uma 1:1, não uma 1:4.